# Unable to update row by objectId using Parse core javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am unable to update row by object id in parse. I am using parse javascript sdk. Below is the code that i tried, but unable to update the column "read" to true. So my code pass in a threadId and user object to get all the comments of the user under the thread. What i want to do is to mark all the comments as read = true. I am not sure why this code is not working? any idea how i can update my rows?

```
readAllById: function(threadId , user){ 

            var ParseString = Parse.Object.extend("Comments");
            var query = new Parse.Query(ParseString);
            query.equalTo("threadId", threadId);
            query.equalTo("user" , user);
            query.ascending("createdAt");
            query.include("user");
            query.include("item");
            return query.find().then(function(response){

                 for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++ ) {

                    console.log(response[i]);
                  var object_id = response[i].id;
                  query.set("id", object_id);
                  query.set("read", true);
                  query.save();
                }

            }, function(error){
                //something went wrong!
            });

        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I got it working by using this code below

```
 readAllById: function(threadId , user){ 

            var ParseString = Parse.Object.extend("Comments");
            var query = new Parse.Query(ParseString);
            query.equalTo("threadId", threadId);
            query.equalTo("user" , user);
            query.ascending("createdAt");
            query.include("user");
            query.include("item");
            return query.find().then(function(response){

                 for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++ ) {

                   var result = Parse.Object.extend("Comments");

                    var result = new Parse.Query(result);
                    query.get(response[i].id,{
                        success: function(result) {
                            result.set('read', true);
                            result.save();
                        }
                    });

                }

            }, function(error){
                //something went wrong!
            });

        },
```

Comment: Thanks, It saved my precious time :)